# Check whether an element exist inside a structure in C

Tags: c, struct

If i have a structure say "apple", so is there a way to check whether a particular element say "color" exist inside the structure?

```
struct apple A{
char color;
int pack;
}
```

The function which uses this may be knowing the internals of this structure other than its name.....

Comment: In what scenario is this plausible?

Comment: You are speaking of reflection. I don't think c supports that

Comment: @Smac89 could you give us an example of reflection ? and what language supports it?

Comment: @Smac89: Not necessarily. Similar thing could be done with C++ [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

Comment: Just a comment on what scenario this is plausible...

A common case in network socket programming is to initialize the sin_len structure field in socket addresses if it exists.

Current usage that I've seen has to use an auto-configure script to set a macro if the structure field exists, and then use #ifdef to check for the case where sin_len exists in struct sockaddr_in.

It would be nice to be able to get that conditional initialization of the structure field if it exists without having to depend on a two-pass process like the auto-config method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not support what you are after - and in requiring it it sounds like something is wrong with your design.  If you are interpretting a stream then there should be and identifier early on in the stream that indicateds the structure in the stream that follows.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this in C is to use the particular field you are interested in. If the program compiles then it exists. If not, than it either does not or you have other errors.

Comment: The flow is such that when a read request comes to the reading interface, then only it maps with the properties List and tries to take out the property. This is because there are different types of structs the read interface deals with. so its more into a run time issue....

Comment: @GinuJacob: When it is a runtime issue, you use meta-information to determine the type of the data you read. Without that meta information you cannot solve the problem even theoretically because structure is merely a compile-time concept that doesn't even exist in runtime.